# C++ error C2440 when getting native pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, native, local, command-line-interface

Haven't write C++ code for long, and what I am trying to do is very simple.
I'd like to create a local instance of a native class.
Then pass a point to that class to another method.
The code is as following:

```
someclass instance();
someclass* pInstance = &instance;
```

I am getting a compilation error as following:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'someclass (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'someclass *'
```

This is a C++ class library which have both native and CLI code. Is this error related to CLI been turned on for the project? What is the syntax to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someclass instance()` is a function pointer as you can see from the error message.
Change it to `someclass instance`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I though instantiating an object of a class with no argument in constructor should have parenthesis as well. I think I've wrote too much C#.

Comment: yes I agree, it's counter intuitive. Especially since writing `someclass *instance = new someclass();` does not declare a function pointer.

Comment: @Bishoy: That's why `someclass instance{};` is preferred in C++. It's unambiguous.